# Can't bind UDT socket from existing UDP socket

Tags: sockets, rust, network-programming, udp, hole-punching

I'm using rust wrapper ([udt-0.1.0](https://docs.rs/udt/0.1.0/udt/index.html)) for the UDT Library  and I'm not managing to bind a UDT socket to an existing UDP socket.

```rust
use std::net::UdpSocket;
use udt::*; // 0.2.0

fn main() {
    let udp_sock = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:8000").unwrap();
    let udt_sock = UdtSocket::new(SocketFamily::AFInet, SocketType::Stream).unwrap();
    udt_sock.bind_from(udp_sock).unwrap();
}
```

Whenever I try to execute this code I'm met with an Error:

```
5003: Operation not supported: Bad parameters: Bad file descriptor.
```

Comment: @Stargateur I've updated the post.

Comment: why do you not use the last 0.2 version ?

Comment: @Stargateur my bad I am actually using the 0.2 version.